# Sufficient condition for Lagrange function to be maximum or minimum

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

In optimization by Lagrange method, what is the sufficient condition for the Lagrange function to be minimum or maximum? Of course , I do know that in direct replacement method, Hessian matrix  being positive definite is helpful(to determine  maximumness) . I would appreciate in advance anybody answering me.